# merge tag-based results?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I get reputation from [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) as 2 different technologies - shouldn't that be just one tag and sum up to a "python reputation" regardless of version?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They will be merged if they are synonyms. `Python 2.7` is not a synonym of `python`(https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-2.7/synonyms)

**If the tags are not synonyms then merging will lead into invalid score.**

If a question is tagged under `python` as well as `python2.7`, then answerer will get scores added to both the tags from a single post itself.

**For ex:**
A user has 11 score from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790063/5832518). It will be put into `python` as well as `python 2.7` in his tag badges.
[image: scoring for tag badges]

---